# I keep getting this "Error while processingC/C++(clang-diagnostic-error)"

Tags: c

i am a newborn in c and i'm getting this error that says

"Error while processingC/C++(clang-diagnostic-error)
stddef.h(216, 23): typedef redefinition with different types ('unsigned int' vs 'unsigned long long')"

i don't know what it means or or what or where i have to change the code because the little red line is under the # and it's saying there's three errors even though there is only one red line

please explain it to me like i'm i barely know c

the code is supposed to ask for a number then devide it by every number smaller then it and when the devision result is a whole number it prints "G" and the deviser and if the result is a double it prints "b" and the non-deviser(?)

here the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(){

    int N;
    float x;
    int i = 1;
    int G = 'G';
    char b = 'b';
    while (1 == 1){
        scanf("%d\n",N);
        while(i < N){
            x = N/i ;
            int y = x;
            if ( x == y){
                printf("%c,%i",G , i);
            }
            else{
                printf("%c,%i", b , i);
            }
            i = i++;
        }
        while (1 == 1){
            int l;
        }
    }
}
```

i didn't try any solutions or anything because i don't know what it is and asking a question here is the first thing that i though of

Comment: This statement scanf("%d\n",N); is already wrong.

Comment: as i said i am a newborn in c so i don't know why it's wrong

Comment: Read a book on C for beginners where there is shown how to use scanf with integers. And at first read compiler messages.

Comment: And what does this loop         while (1 == 1){
            int l;
        } mean?

Comment: the while loop is just so the console app doesn't close immediately after the code is ran and i don't know any other way to stop it from closing immediatly

Comment: There is no `unsigned` in the code shown, so either it is not the code that produced the error message about `unsigned int` and `unsigned long long` or there is something very wrong in your C installation (some bug in `<stdio.h>` or things it includes) or in your build tools or how you are using them (such as telling them to include incorrect files).

Comment: i don't know about the c installation but the way i installed the compiler is I just downloaded the mingw-get-setup and when it was done installing i added the bin path to the system environment variables which i suspect is where the problem is coming from now that you mentioned it

Comment: Hi  -- [here](https://godbolt.org/z/sMYqzscYj) is your code with some comments and changes -- hope it helps a little.

Comment: Unfortunately your (first?) C example has too many errors. You might want to look at [the definitive C book guide and list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to obtain at least one of them.

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't see anything in your code that would trigger that error message.
2. The variable `G` is a constant so I would just hard-code it in the output format string.  You can also make it a compile symbolic constant with `#define G 'G'` or a constant variable `const int G = 'G';`.
3. `scanf("%d\n", N)` requires an address of the variable so `scanf("%d", &N)`.
4. `scanf("%d\n", ...)` is probably a mistake as it will wait for non-whitespace after the newline before returning.  Leave out the "\n".
5. Always check the return value of `scanf()`.  Otherwise you may be operating on uninitialized variables.
6. `while(1==1)` is strange way to write an infinite loop.  The shortest option is `for(;;)`; `while(1)` is also widely used.
7. `int y = x; if(x == y)` is always true so you can eliminate dead code.
8. `i = i++` is improperly sequenced `i == i; i++;` and you probably just want `i++;`.
9. The last infinite loop doesn't do anything and the variable `l` is not used.  Eliminate dead code.
10. It's a a really good idea to minimize the scope of variables.  It makes your code easier to reason about.
11. (Change) I added a newline to `printf()` format string for readability and to ensure the output is flushed.

Here is what you end up with:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i = 1;
    for(;;) {
        int N;
        if(scanf("%d", &N) != 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "scanf failed\n");
            return 1;
        }
        for(; i < N; i++)
            printf("G, %i\n", i);
    }
}
```

and example run:

```
2
G, 1
4
G, 2
G, 3
```

Comment: If the above answered your question please accept it by clicking the check mark next to it.